# How can I fix a Unhealthy deployment state for my Azure Machine Learning Model Deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

"Unhealthy" deployment state with my Azure Machine Learning Model Deployment
[image: Unhealty Status]

So, I have been working on my Azure Machine Learning Studio to build a classification model and already created a real-time inference for it.
[image: Azure Model Design]

After I try to deploy the model, while it actually succesfully deployed, the status in unhealthy. Is there any mistake that I made? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Below is my inference pipeline.

[image]

I deployed it in both **AksCompute** and **Azure Container Instance**.
Initially it was in **Unhealthy** state, later it took below time for deployment.

[image]

Deployment with **Azure Container Instance** it took about 35 mins.

[image]

Deployment with **AksCompute** it took about 15 mins.

[image]

So, it may take time for deployment based on your compute resource, or you need to check compute cluster used, is it provisioned properly or not.